# Trying to use cgroups in debian wheezy and no daemons

Tags: debian, cgroups

I'm trying to follow guides about cgroups, like [this one](http://hydra.geht.net/tino/english/faq/debian/squeeze/cgroups/) as example. I'm not really sure to clearly understand how cgroups is supposed to work currently. But I'm sure of one thing: all the guides I find document the usages of `/etc/cgconfig.conf` and `/etc/cgrules.conf`. Those files are supposed to be loaded by two daemons which I think should be named `cgred` and `cgconfig`.

Under Debian Squeeze, it seems like those two daemons where automatically installed by installing `cgroup-bin`. But in Wheezy, those daemons do not exist anymore in the package: http://packages.debian.org/fr/wheezy/amd64/cgroup-bin/filelist .

I'm simply trying to create some kind of shared hosting solution and I would like to limit the RAM usage of my users. I was told about cgroups and wanted to try it, but I don't understand how to use that version in Wheezy, and I can't find any documentation to help me.

Could someone tell me what to do? Is that package broken? Is there some completely new (and undocumented) way to configure cgroups?

Comment: The init-scripts are missing. There is one provided in /usr/share/doc/cgroup-bin/cgred for the cgrulesengined daemon, but it is broken as it is. The other one is probably not a daemon, but just the cgconfigparser that should be run at startup to create your cgroups. When I have a solution, I will likely post it to you here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As an alternative to using `cgroup-bin` look at `systemd`, it uses cgroups to group/separate processes of users and usage of resource controllers should be fine.

However, in the following I will try to answer your original question on `cgroup-bin`

Since there are multiple issues with this, I step through:

The init-scripts are missing in the packages. There is however `/usr/share/doc/cgroup-bin/examples/cgred` which works partially (starts up `cgrulesengd` for me at system boot, but does not restart the daemon yet). Remove the line sourcing some init-functions that do not exist in debian before using it. You can however also start it via `/etc/rc.local`.

I have the following `cgconfig.conf`

```
mount {
  cpu    = /sys/fs/cgroup ;
  cpuset = /sys/fs/cgroup ;
  memory = /sys/fs/cgroup ;
}

group users {
  memory {
    memory.soft_limit_in_bytes = 512M;
    memory.limit_in_bytes = 1G;
  }

# cpuset seems to be obligatory, adjust the parameters
  cpuset {
    cpuset.cpus = 0-7 ;
    cpuset.mems = 0 ;
  }
}
```

To load cgconfig.conf execute `cgconfigparser -l /etc/cgconfig.conf`. You can do this in `/etc/rc.local` at startup.

Debian disables the `memory` subsystem by default in the kernel, so you need to activate it if you need it: set the kernel command line in `/etc/default/grub` to load the memory subsystem: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet cgroup_enable=memory"`. Call `update-grub` and reboot.

You should now have a mounted cgroup file system in `/sys/fs/cgroup` with a `users` directory inside.

Try `cgexec -g memory,cpuset:users <command>` and watch the syslog for errors.

Answer (score 0):

Fully LSB compatible init scripts for cgconfig and cgred can be found here:

https://gist.github.com/divanikus/99d80a04073833ea8389